# Flyway-Databricks integration

Tags: databricks, database-migration, azure-databricks, flyway

I am exploring Flyway for Database migration. I want to integrate it with Databricks. Have performed some tasks and trying to overcome the following error.

Till now I have performed

1. Flyway [setup](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/commandline/#download-and-installation) on the local machine.
2. Copied [spark-jdbc databricks](https://databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download) driver to drivers folder of Flyway
3. Updated the Flyway config

```html
Picked-up the jdbc url from databricks cluster and created a token in databricks. Added these configurations in flyway config.
flyway.url= jdbc:spark://<hostname>:443/<database>;transportMode=http;ssl=1;AuthMech=3;httpPath=<httpPath>;UID=token;PWD=<token>
flyway.driver=com.simba.spark.jdbc.Driver
flyway.user=<dummy_username>
flyway.password=<token>
```

4. Error received

```html
ERROR: Unexpected error
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle jdbc:spark://<host>:443/<database>
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseTypeRegister.getDatabaseTypeForUrl(DatabaseTypeRegister.java:55)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:109)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:89)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.configure(ClassicConfiguration.java:1653)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.configuration(FluentConfiguration.java:1038)
        at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:159)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Error - org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to
> handle jdbc:spark://:443/

This error occurred because of different versions of drivers.

Try with downgraded version. If it doesn’t work, you can try with different combinations of configuration.

For similar issue you can refer this [github link](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3355)

Comment: Hey @Abhishek, tried downgrading the flyway version to 8.2.0. But still getting the same error. Please suggest any other tryouts.

Comment: Please try with version 8.0.0